# In FFmpeg, using -filter_complex, how can I overlay and blend at the same time?

Tags: ffmpeg, alphablending, video-watermarking

My code works to combine three videos, resize the videos to 1920X1080, resize the watermark to  the correct size, and then overlays the watermark to the lower left hand side. Then converts to the intended codecs for Youtube.
My question is how do I Blend at the same time using the -filter_complex workflow?
Currently, I have the following workflow that does everything but set the opacity

```
ffmpeg -y -i fancy movie.mov -i logo.png -i in.mov -i out.mov -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -b:v 50000k -preset veryfast -tune film -profile:v high -x264opts cabac=1:keyint=16:bframes=2:keyint_min=15 -c:a libvo_aacenc -ab 128K -ar 48000 -filter_complex "[0:0] scale=1920X1080 [main]; [2:0] scale=1920X1080 [start]; [3:0] scale=1920X1080 [end]; [start] [2:1] [main] [0:1] [end] [3:1] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1 [prog]; [1:0] scale=480:90 [wm]; [prog] [wm] overlay=36:main_h-overlay_h-45" fart.mp4
```

I'm trying to add "blend=all_opacity=0.7" in the last step so the watermark will screen against the background. If I just add

```
[prog] [wm] overlay=36:main_h-overlay_h-45, blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.7" fart.mp4
```

I get the error, **Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_blend_6**

If I try a semicolon instead,

```
[prog] [wm] overlay=36:main_h-overlay_h-45; blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.7
```

I get the error, **Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_blend_6** which makes me think that it's expecting something like [input 1] [input 2] blend command [output]. The problem is that I need it to overlay and blend.

I tried simplifying the code to just test if the blend operation was working properly.

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:0] scale=1920x1080 [wm]; [1:0] scale=1920x1080 [prog], [wm][prog] blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.7" fart.mp4
```

I got the error **First input link top parameters (size 1920x1080, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding second input link bottom parameters (1920x1080, SAR 243:80)
Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_blend_2**

So, in addition to the trouble with combining of filters, I'm also having an issue with resizing the watermark as FFMpeg sees it as a different aspect ratio than the other videos.

This is my second day with FFmpeg, so any help would be appreciated.

I'm currently working with FFMpeg version N-61061-gf34cceb

Comment: to get rid of the SAR problem pipe the failing stream through a `[prog] setsar=sar=1 [progsared]`

Comment: thank you, I'm able to test the graphic at least!

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the input into 2 outputs and use them in the next blending filter before overlaying.

I have example running command:

```html
ffmpeg -y -i image.png -i image1.png -i image2.png -i image3.png -filter_complex "
color=c=white:s=2560x1920:d=1 [base];
[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=2560:1920, format=rgba, colorchannelmixer=aa=0.2, setsar=1:1 [background];
[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, format=rgba, colorchannelmixer=aa=1, scale=776:776, split=2 [capture1x][capture1y];
[capture1x][capture1y] blend=all_mode='multiply':all_opacity=1 [capture1];
[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, format=rgba, colorchannelmixer=aa=1, scale=857:857, split=2 [capture2x][capture2y];
[capture2x][capture2y] blend=all_mode='lighten':all_opacity=1 [capture2];
[3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, format=rgba, colorchannelmixer=aa=1, scale=640:853, split=2 [capture3x][capture3y];
[capture3x][capture3y] blend=all_mode='lighten':all_opacity=1 [capture3];
[base][background] overlay=x=0:y=0 [backOverlay];
[backOverlay][capture1] overlay=x=144:y=233 [tmp1];
[tmp1][capture2] overlay=x=269:y=343 [tmp2];
[tmp2][capture3] overlay=x=1483:y=363" -frames:v 1 -vcodec png  /Users/viktorspasevski/Desktop/out.png
```

Greetings from Macedonia!